# Deploy images TeamCity Octopus without Git

Tags: teamcity, octopus

Hi I have a site that is in git using team city and octopus for deployment.

The issue i have is i have thousands of images on my dev environment which need to go to staging. I dont want to check into git. What is the best way of automating this step without adding to git. I am using teamcity and octopus for the website deployment at the moment.

Comment: The best solution to this problem is to store the images on a content delivery network (CDN). This way all your links point to the images that are stored offsite and you don't need to worry about storing them under source control - the caveat being that you don't have the ability to rollback changes you might make to them.

Comment: which cdn for images would you recommend

Comment: Very hard to recommend one over another - it all depends on the features you're looking for. https://www.cloudflare.com/features-cdn is a good starting point.